# Read files *.dat with fixed width

Tags: python, dataframe, fixed-width

I have the width of each column that varies between 1 and 10. The values are floating point and integers.

Sample:

```
171991302711523   6.3  7.58 216.0  0.002022 15.758774 25.00  1.00041555  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The split columns are:

```
0,5,5,5,6,6,6,10,10,6,6,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
```

There are 10,000 rows like this and I need to bring all these values to dataframe. I tried **pandas.read_fwf** but for some reason, it doesn't work with columns of varying widths (especially column with width 1 makes the job harder)

Comment: Since you have not tagged a specific language, you could try using the `read.fwf` function of R. It can handle something like this easily.

Comment: It'd help if you showed your attempt at using `pandas.read_fwf` as that's the correct approach...